# Rotating in 3d space - random values of x,y,z rotation so end result = beginning

Tags: 3d, rotation

Can anyone tell me the formula for determining what combination of x,y,z rotation values will give the same result as a normalized object(no rotation) in 3d space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know both the end result and the initial state, then it's just basic matrix multiplication. You'd have to find the angles used to rotate the object (one for the x-axis, y-axis and z-axis) and left-multiply your coordinate vectors by this guy:

[image]

Comment: can you please tell us what those greek symbols correspond to?  is theta the x-rotation?  what are the other two symbols even called?  arg.

Comment: Theta, phi, psi ;) They are [Euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). Look at the second diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing uniformly distributed random angles [-pi, pi] will not lead to a uniformly random rotation axis on the sphere! Wikipedia has a [nice explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) about this phenomenon, which is called the "gimbal lock". See "Fast Random Rotation Matrices" by James Arvo for one algorithm that produces uniformly random rotations.